# Is There a Way to Get a List of Aliases? (Discord py)

Tags: python, bots, discord, aliases

So I've been stuck on this for a while and can't seem to find the answer online...

Is there a way to show a user all of the aliases that a command has?

Example: **.sum** has the aliases: **.add, .plus, .addNums,** etc...

Mainly I just need a way to "get" a list of aliases for a given command.

I found **bot.get_command("aliasName")**, which will return the command that this alias is tied to, however I cannot find a way to get a list of aliases from a given command.

I've checked [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.aliases), but could not find what I needed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would the [`aliases` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.aliases) of [`discord.ext.commands.Command`](discord.ext.commands.Command) do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from discord.ext import commands

sum_command = commands.Bot.get_command(bot, "sum")

sum_aliases = sum_command.aliases
```

Found it!

Answer (score 1):

The default `help` command does this by default.  You would invoke it for the command `sum` like:

```
.help sum
```

and the response would be something like

```
.[sum|plus|addNums]
```

Comment: This works, however I have overwritten the default help command with my own `bot.remove_command("help")` Also I need to access the alias list within my own code.