# discord.py list of command aliases?

Tags: discord, discord.py, command, alias

I know the way to get list of all commands but idk how to get aliases list for all/specify command.

```py
# List of all bot commands
bot_commands = [_.name for _ in self.bot.commands]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is There a Way to Get a List of Aliases? (Discord py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60779632/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-aliases-discord-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it ;)

```py
# List of all bot commands with aliases
bot_commands = [
    *[_.name for _ in self.bot.commands],
    *sum([_.aliases for _ in self.bot.commands], [])
]

# aliases list for specify command
aliases = lambda c: [_.aliases for _ in self.bot.commands if _.name == c]

clear_aliases = aliases('clear')
# output for example - ['purge', 'p', 'c']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's an [`aliases`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command.aliases) attribute for the command.

```py
command_info = [f'{command.name} has aliases {command.aliases}' for command in self.bot.commands]
await ctx.send(command_info)
```

For example, this outputs [image]